# Small switch to power something off or on

Tags: smart-home

I need a remotely controllable switch to power my ventilation off and on. So it should switch 220V off/on, and it should be small because the available space is 80mmx54mmx21mm.

My homematic switch actuator is too thick for the job.

Really great would be something that I can connect (through some intermediate stages) with homematic. But this is not really necessary.

Comment: Have you considered the Philips Hue Wall Switch Module (using Zigbee) or one of the Shelly modules (using WiFi)? Neither is directly compatible with Homematic (as far as I know) but either will fit in those dimensions (with room to spare).

Comment: @jcaron I looked more deeply into the Hue Wall Switch Module. It seems like it does not actually switch the power on and off, but it connects input and output power and provides an interface for a standard wall switch.

Comment: Ah indeed, don’t know what I was thinking, this is a controller rather than an actual switch (one would usually use a smart plug on the socket instead). The Shelly modules are actual switches though. There may also be relays you can mount on a DIN rail on your electrical panel, if that can make sense in your setup.